# Celery Emails and Accessing Mailbox

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, celery

I'm in the process of moving my emails over to Celery tasks to run asychronously.

Porting over my existing tests I'm struggling with an AssertionError when I attempt to access the mail.outbox.

I assume this is due to the mailbox being created within the Celery thread rather than within the scope of the test.

Is there any way around this to test the email has succesfully sent?

I've pretty much ran out of ideas on the best way to approach this.

#### Task

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.conf import settings

from smtplib import SMTPException 

CONFIRMATION_MESSAGE = 'Thank you! Your enquiry has been received and one of our team will be in touch shortly.'

@shared_task
def send_contact_email(recipient, subject):

    try: 

        #send a confirmation email
        email_content = render_to_string('base_email.html', {'message': 'message'})

        # Create an EmailMultiAlternatives object
        email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
            subject=subject,
            body=CONFIRMATION_MESSAGE,
            from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, 
            to=[recipient]
        )

        # Attach the HTML content to the email
        email.attach_alternative(email_content, "text/html")

        # Send the email
        email.send()
    except SMTPException as e:
        # Handle any SMTP exceptions
        print(f"SMTPException occurred: {str(e)}")
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle any other exceptions
        print(f"Exception occurred: {str(e)}")
```

#### Test

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings
from django.core import mail
from unittest.mock import patch
    
from contact.tasks import send_contact_email

# Set CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER to True in your test configuration
override_settings(CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True)

class ContactFormEmail(TestCase):

    @patch('contact.tasks.send_contact_email.apply')
    def test_send_contact_email(self, mock_send_contact_email):

        form_data = {
            'name': 'John Doe',
            'subject': 'Subject',
            'email': 'john.doe@example.com',
            'message': 'A test message'
        }

        # Call the Celery task
        result = send_contact_email.apply(args=[form_data['email'], form_data['subject']])
        result.wait()

        # Assert that the task was called with the expected arguments
        mock_send_contact_email.assert_called_once_with(args=[form_data['email'], form_data['subject']])

        # TODO: Figure out issues with the testing mail.outbox
        self.assertEquals(len(mail.outbox), 1)
```